# How do you put variables into an UPDATE statement using sqlite?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have put in all of the code which I think is relevant  to the question and my problem is with the last 4 lines in the if statement. I have tried defining 'term' as a different variable in case the problem was with the transfer between 2 functions but this still didn't work. I have also looked around on the internet but all of the answers appear to only be relevant to putting set values into the statement and not variables.

```
    def FindItem(n = ''):
        #Finds products by GTIN
        shopping = 'yes'
        while shopping == 'yes':
            find("GTIN8", getNum("Enter the GTIN-8 of the product that you want: "))
            shopping = input('do you want to add any more Items to your shop? ')
        print('This is your recipt:')
        recipt = open('temp.txt')
        for eachline in recipt:
            print(eachline, end = '')
        recipt.close()
        return os.remove('temp.txt')

    def find(search, term):
        # Helper function for the find function.
        with connect("GTINb.db") as db:
            cursor = db.cursor()
            sql = "select * from GTINb where {} = ?".format(search)
            cursor.execute(sql,(term,))
            db.commit()
            results = cursor.fetchall()
            if results:
                results = str(results)
                temp = open('temp.txt', 'a')
                temp.write(results)
                temp.write('\n')
                temp.close
                with connect("GTINb.db") as db:
                    sql = "UPDATE GTINb SET stockcur=stockcur-1 WHERE GTIN8=term"
                    cursor.execute(sql)
                return
            else:
                temp = open('temp.txt', 'a')
                temp.write('Product not found')
                temp.write('\n')
                temp.close
                return
```

Comment: Using Python's `format` on a string of SQL is a big red flag.

Comment: Are you perhaps missing the placeholder + value passing in your UPDATE sql? `GTIN8=?` and `cursor.execute(sql, (term,))`.

Comment: You are missing the function call operator `()` on `temp.close`, so the buffer might not be flushed.